# PHP Form Submission without a client

Tags: php, http-post

A third party tool that we're forced to use has no standard API. The closest they have is automatically generated webforms which enter stuff into the tool's database. That'd fine and all if we were using the tool for a client-facing website, but we're using the tool for internal processing and already have the data in an array.

So my question is, what would be the best method in PHP to submit form data without needing a client? My difficulty is on where to start on this.

Comment: The first thing I can say is cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the PHP [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) library.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'liljoshu',
    'site' => 'StackOverflow',
    'profile' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/2044183/liljoshu'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com/some_page/');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ajb-34e

Comment: Question, with PostFields... I'm looking for an answer and haven't found one yet about the fields that the array gets put into. What determines what array entries go in which field? Is it the order of the array matching the fields in target website or is it the array identifier names matching the Field IDs?

Edit: NVM, just found the answer. From php.net:"This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value."

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will accept an associative array where the `key` is equivalent to the `name` field of an input. The example array is functionally equivalent to this html: `<input type="hidden" name="name" value="liljoshu" /><input type="hidden" name="site" value="StackOverflow" /><input type="hidden" name="profile" value="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2044183/liljoshu" />`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew (I had an edit that shows I found the answer, but thanks for confirming). I've been running the code, and although it executes, not yet having the desired response. I'm wondering, CURLOPT_URL... should that be targeting the webform or the webform's target?

Comment: You will need to target the webform's target. If you are familiar with your web browser's developer tools you can monitor the network tab for POST submission data. This will help you understand which fields you need to submit. If the target requires authentication you will need to add support in your cURL request (e.g. via header or cookie).

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That'll cut down on my bughunting by a lot. Although I've used PHP for a long time, this is my first time using cURL. So the help is definitely appreciated.